# Plotting cot(x) in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot{cot(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried to plot cot(x) using the above code but it shows me a graph like this
[image]

What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are simply not enough points being sampled:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[domain=0:360,samples=361]{cot(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: no error]

Edit: I noticed that the scale on the y-axis in your example is given as $n\cdot10^4$, a fuller description of the problem is that the default sampling picked a point very close to $0$, and so the value of $\cot(x)$ at that point was very large, making all the others lie very close to the x-axis. A similar effect occurs here:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[domain=-5:5,samples=1024]{cot(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: same error as in Q]

To avoid this sort of problem in future, think about if there are any contingencies where the system will sample near extremes of a function.

Comment: will it take the argument of cot as degree by default?

Comment: @KSreerag Yes, but you can write `cot(deg(x))` to convert to radians.  It's also possible to write `cot(x r)` but personally I find that notation very unclear.

Comment: Yes, the trigonometric functions in pgfplot take degrees by default. Search the [documentation](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) for "`\sin`" and you will see several examples where plots are made in radians but have to be converted to degrees before calling `\sin()`.